# Difference between Qt::QueuedConnection and Qt::DirectConnection when connecting a signal to a lambda

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qwidget, qthread

Let's consider a scenario of two `QObjects`, `senderObject` of type `SenderObject` and `receiverObject` of type `ReceiverObject`. `senderObject` has been created on a worker thread while `receiverObject` has been created on the main thread. Now let's asssume `SenderObject` has a signal `somethingsChanged` and let's consider the following the code snippet:

**Snippet1:**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
  QThread t;
  SenderObject senderObject = new SenderObject();
  senderObject.moveToThread(&t);
  ReceiverObject receiverObject = new ReceiverObject();
  //in this case we know for a fact that receiverObject's 
  //onSomethingsChanged() will be called on the main thread
  QObject::connect(senderObject, &SenderObject::somethingsChanged, 
  receiverObject, &ReceiverObject::onSomethingsChanged, Qt::QueuedConnection);
  t.start();
  return a.exec();
}
```

Now let's consider the following code snippet:

**Snippet2:**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
  QThread t;
  SenderObject senderObject = new SenderObject();
  senderObject.moveToThread(&t);
  //where will qDebug() << "Hello, world" be executed? 
  //On the main thread again since the lambda lives on the main thread?
  QObject::connect(senderObject, &SenderObject::somethingsChanged, 
  []{qDebug << "Hello, world";});
  t.start();
  return a.exec();
}
```

Will the lambda in Snippet2 be execute on the main thread also since the lambda has been declared on the main thread, or will it get executed in the same thread as `senderObject`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's our class `SenderObject:`

```
class Sender : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
 public:
  explicit Sender() : QObject() {
    _timer.setInterval(1000);
    connect(&_timer, &QTimer::timeout, this,
            [this] { emit somethingsChanged(); });
    _timer.start();
  }

 signals:
  void somethingsChanged();

 private:
  QTimer _timer;
};
```

Since there is no overload of `QObject::connect` that will take a lambda and a `Qt` connection type parameter, Snippet2 will execute in the sender's thread, which is a worker thread.

In order to force the lambda to execute on the main thread, here is a workaround:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
  QThread t;
  SenderObject senderObject = new SenderObject();
  senderObject.moveToThread(&t);
  QObject::connect(senderObject, &SenderObject::somethingsChanged, new QObject,
  []{qDebug << "Hello, world";}, Qt::QueuedConnection);
  t.start();
  return a.exec();
}
```

Since `new QObject` is called on the main thread, the lambda will also get executed on the main thread.

Or, if we don't like to see `new`, this is what will work:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
  QThread t;
  SenderObject senderObject = new SenderObject();
  senderObject.moveToThread(&t);
  QObject object;
  QObject::connect(senderObject, &SenderObject::somethingsChanged, &object,
  []{qDebug << "Hello, world";}, Qt::QueuedConnection);
  t.start();
  return a.exec();
}
```

Or, even a better solution will be to use `qApp`, which is an instance of the application and a singleton and available from anywhere.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
  QThread t;
  SenderObject senderObject = new SenderObject();
  senderObject.moveToThread(&t);
  QObject::connect(senderObject, &SenderObject::somethingsChanged, qApp,
  []{qDebug << "Hello, world";}, Qt::QueuedConnection);
  t.start();
  return a.exec();
}
```